# Drupal 8 Drupal.behaviors without jquery

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-8, pure-js

Is there a way to add drupal behaviors to a theme without invoking jquery in Drupal 8?

This is what the tutorial show:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('input.myCustomBehavior', context).once('myCustomBehavior').each(function () {
        // Apply the myCustomBehaviour effect to the elements only once.
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

But i want to use pure js without invoking jquery, something like this:

```
(function (Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      context.querySelector('input.myCustomBehavior').classList.add('processed');
    }
  };
})(Drupal);
```

I understand that modules may invoke jquery on their own but i still would like to remove it from my scripts if possible and still have it run after ajax events.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried your 2nd code block? does it work? if not does it give an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it?

I also did not know this, so went investigating.

It seems that Drupal no longer relys on jQuery's document.ready to fire behaviors.
As seen in [this change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/1994482).

This leads me to believe that the second code block that you posted should work (with Drupal 8.x).

Comment: I have tried multiple versions of what i wrote without success, what you found looks promising but i cant find a way to make it work yet,  `domready(function () { });`  works just the same as `(function () {});` but it wont work after ajax or with bigpipe i also found `domready(function () {  Drupal.attachBehaviors(document, drupalSettings);}); ` but i cant find how to implemented properly.

Comment: In the end your answer lead me to figure it out. It turns out that bigpipe requires jquery therefor it was going counter to what i was doing with js and it caused it to failed when i disabled bigpipe the second code block worked just fined with ajax. Thanks

Comment: Bigpipe does indeed rely on jQuery, as can be seen in [the source](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/big_pipe/js/big_pipe.js?h=8.5.x). This makes me sad :(

Comment: From Drupal 9.3 bigpipe do NOT depend on jQuery anymore. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3204273